# Akka IO reset TCP connection randomly

Tags: java, akka

I created example project of TCP server in Akka IO (source codes in https://github.com/lordjoker/akkatcp) which works on port 9099. During load tests it occured that sending for example 1000 same requests ends with [RST, ACK] which reset TCP connection. On the client side I have following exception:

```
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException: 
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.BinaryTCPClientImpl.read(BinaryTCPClientImpl.java:152) ~[ApacheJMeter_tcp.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPSampler.sample(TCPSampler.java:402) [ApacheJMeter_tcp.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_172]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.BinaryTCPClientImpl.read(BinaryTCPClientImpl.java:134) ~[ApacheJMeter_tcp.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    ... 5 more
```

Whireshark shows:
[image]

I don't have any idea why?